# Angular filtering

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a two ng-repeats that they use a similar filter to hide a specific name:

```
ng-repeat="something in somethingelse | filter:{ name:'!John' }"

ng-repeat="something in somethingelse | filter:{ name:'!Santa' }"
```

I would like to create a filters.js file to keep this logic outside my template. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems based on what I noticed from your sample that maybe this is not a job for a custom filter but for your controller:

```
ng-repeat="something in somethingelse | filter: myFilter"
```

In your **controller**

```
$scope.myFilter= { name:'!John' }
```